# adding an obj to new layer in blender 2.79 and linking the existing object to the new collection in blender 2.8 same?

Tags: python, animation, layers, collections

I was following a tutorial for fish animation. In the tutorial they are adding a plane and adding that plane into separate layers. Then all operations are performed on that plan. So in Blender 2.8 how to achieve that? I tried by creating new collection and linking the plane object to the new collection ? Is this the right way to do?

My purpose is to hide the plane object while rendering animation 
Can anyone help me to solve that with python ?

Comment: @batFINGER Can you help me out?

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic.

Answer (score 1):

My aim was to hide the plane object while rendering. I achieved by adding plane and fish in different collections and unlinking the plane object from all other collections and then disabling that specific collection for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In the upper left corner there is the filter-button, which gives you access to 7 restriction-buttons (for example disable in renders).